# How can i add a Polyline to an pane Array?

Tags: arrays, javafx, pane

Ok so here what I am doing. I am trying to make a program that uses a data stream of 20 random doubles, then uses then 20 random doulbe to make 10 different polylines.
all of which need to be on separate stackPanes.  I read the data stream fine but when I try to add the polylines to an array of StackPanes I get an error.
So what I am asking is can you do this?

```
package project.pkg3;

public class adf extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Button prevBut = new Button();
    prevBut.setText("Previous");
    Button next = new Button();
    next.setText("Next");
    int scenePane = 0;
    int numOfFiles = 10;
    int numOfDoubles = 20;
    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;
    StackPane[] sPane = new StackPane[numOfFiles];

    HBox hbox = new HBox();
    hbox.setSpacing(10);
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    hbox.getChildren().add(prevBut);
    hbox.getChildren().add(next);
    hbox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
    root.getChildren().add(hbox);


    for (int i = 0; i < numOfFiles; i++) {

        try {
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("temp" + i + ".dat"));

            Polyline polyline = new Polyline(input.readDouble(), input.readDouble(), input.readDouble(), input.readDouble(), input.readDouble(), input.readDouble(), input.readDouble(), input.readDouble(), input.readDouble(), input.readDouble());
            input.close();

            sPane[i].getChildren().add(polyline);
        } catch (EOFException e) {

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(adf.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }




    }
```

Comment: I was wanting to do this because i have to create a eventhandler for going to the next polyline

Comment: What error do you get?  Please include a stack trace in your question.  Also include some sample data files, so that somebody could replicate your error using only the information you provided in your question.